# Git print files in Windows Format

Tags: windows, git, command-prompt

The most common use case I deal with `git` is to checkout file or remove or add file from `Windows Command prompt`.

I don't intend to use fancy gui tools. I like to work with keyboard and command prompt as much as possible.

So whenever I ask git status or any other report, git prints the file name like this

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
Tasks/Test/MyTest.js
```

The problem is, I can't just copy paste that text and use `git checkout` or `git add` anything. Since `Windows` can't understand **`/`** it expects you to give with **`\`**

Is there anyway `git` can print the info in `Windows` format or `Windows` can accept the `*nix` format `[del Tasks/Test/MyTest.js]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested Git using the Command Prompt and I had no trouble running `git add` on a file path which included forward slashes, so I don't see your problem as being reproducible.

Another option for you to consider is to use the Git Bash command line tool which ships with the Windows download of Git.  The bash is a window, similar in appearance to the Command Prompt, but more powerful.  On my Windows setup the Git Bash program is located here:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
```

The Git Bash tool does not make a distinction between `/` and `\` in the path.  Since either will work, you only need to copy the output you want, which is also easy and straightforward.

And good for you for sticking to command line Git.  I believe you will become a stronger Git user by learning the nuts and bolts first on the command line.

Comment: Beigeleisen, completely agree with you. I used to work with `bash` and I liked the powerful `command line` and `git`. I am trying to be the same with `cmd` rather than mouse clicks :(

Comment: So can we assume then you want a Command Prompt solution then?

Comment: yes absolutely. I am looking for `cmd` solutions only :)

Comment: I just tested using forward slashes and it works fine.  Actually, the Command Prompt has allowed both `/` and `\ ` for a while now.